# Flutter DevTools 2.20.1 network request and response tab empty

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-devtools

Flutter DevTools has recently been updated to version 2.20.1 and since then my request and response in the network tabs are empty. I can still see the headers of the request.

I have tried:

- Re opening VS Code
- Flutter clean
- Deleting and reinstalling the Flutter and Dart package in VS Code
- Switching to DevTools in my web browser

Any ideas of what the problem could be? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you run your app in profile mode?

Comment: @CavinMacwan I'm running my app in debug mode

Comment: Then you can try to run in profile mode and check then

Comment: @CavinMacwan doesn't work either, it's the same as in debug mode. My header tab contains some information but the request and response tabs are empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/5194) with Flutter 3.7.0 – 3.7.1 – 3.7.2,  DevTools 2.20.1

You can use [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/5194#issuecomment-1423604738) to run DevTools as Desktop app

Comment: still error on 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I am using `dio` so it couldn't be showed :(

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler?utm_source=android-studio#troubleshoot-network-connection

[image]